# Flutter Image format into byte fomat

Tags: flutter

How to get image in byte format using flutter on_click of button  and also how to stored image in gallery on any devices please help out on this.

```
  onPressed: () {
    isVideo = false;
    _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource.camera);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get the bytes:

```
  onImageButtonPressed(Future<File> futureFile) {
    var file = await futureFile;
    var bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
  }
```